# SAPUI5 odata model cant load data.js

Tags: javascript, sapui5

When I initialise my oData model I am getting a few errors regarding an data.js file. My coding for the Odata Model looks like this:

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(oServiceUrl)
```

when executing this code, the following error appears.

```
failed to load 'sap/ui/thirdparty/datajs.js' from ./sap/ui/thirdparty/datajs.js: 404 - NOT FOUND
Caused by: undefined
```

I get the following error three times..

```
found in negative cache: 'sap/ui/model/odata/ODataMetadata.js' from <unknown>/sap/ui/model/odata/ODataMetadata: Error: failed to load 'sap/ui/thirdparty/datajs.js' from ./sap/ui/thirdparty/datajs.js: 404 - NOT FOUND
Caused by: Error: failed to load 'sap/ui/thirdparty/datajs.js' from ./sap/ui/thirdparty/datajs.js: 404 - NOT FOUND
   at j1 (https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js:174:4803)
   at k1 (https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js:174:4896)
   at p1 (https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js:174:7297)
   at r1 (https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js:174:9307)
   at sap.ui.define (https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js:174:11649)
   at q1 (https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js:174:8066)
   at p1 (https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js:174:6249)
   at r1 (https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js:174:9307)
   at sap.ui.define (https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/res
```

This only happens, when the application is deployed to our SAP System. On local host this error doesn't appear (just an error about cross-origin resources).

Comment: Did you add sap/ui/model/odata/ODataModel to your controller's define section?

Comment: WHat do you mean by define section?

Comment: By the way - the OdataModel you are using is deprecated! Instead you should use sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel and in future the sap.ui.model.odata.v4.ODataModel (I think V4 is not production ready yet...).

Comment: You should have a section at the top of your controller where you have a list of defines, similar to imports in java